# How do I use ElicitIntent?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-lex

Imagine you have a bot with 2 intents, and each intent has its own lambda function attached to it.

If a user says "hello" I want to `ElicitIntent` to find out what they want from the bot. Where in the code does this live? Which of the lambda functions? I can't seem to find a place to attach a lambda function to the bot as a whole.

Comment: Read this http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/lambda-input-response-format.html

Answer (score 0):

You should not need an `intent` whose purpose is to decide which `intent` to fire.

The recommended approach for this sort of interaction is to have an extra *FAQ* style `Intent` which fires on "Hello" and "What can you do" etc, that simply echos some information to the user.

Each of the two *real* `intents` with then be selected based on the users following request as if no help was provided.

Answer (score 0):

Lex will determine the intent from what user said, i.e user input.
After that it will call the associated lambda function to that intent where you can do further processing.
If Lex is not able to determine the intent, it will prompt the **Error Handling** message to user.

Answer (score 0):

As has already been mentioned, Lex can infer what intent to trigger using its Natural Language Processing. If you want to read more about that you can [here](https://aws.amazon.com/lex/features/).

However, if you want to specify an intent you can do that using `ElicitSlot`.
This is useful if you need to chain intents, but you should should allow Lex to infer the initial intent based on the user's input.

You can set up a Lambda function to chain intents:

- Create your new Lambda function. You may want to attach CloudWatch permissions to it so you can more easily fix any issues.
- In your Lex bot, go into "Lambda initialization and validation" and select the lambda you just created

In this image, my Lambda function is called `lex-advising-func`:
[image: Screenshot]

This gives Lex access to invoke the Lambda. It will call it for each slot.

Now, chaining your intent:

```
 return {
        dialogAction: {
            type: 'ElicitSlot',
            intentName: <Name of intent to be invoked>,
            slotToElicit: <Name of the slot you want to invoke in that intent>
        }
    }
```

This will change the intent to the one you specify and begin that intent's dialog.

You may also want to check out the [Lex documentation for Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/lambda-input-response-format.html) to give you more insight.

Comment: > intentName: <Name of intent to be invoked>
Does it work for Lex V2?

Comment: @Nicolai I'm not as familiar with V2 but I think the [formatting should be slightly different](https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/lex-dialogflow-fulfillment-lambda)